# A conceptual question regarding pressure in kinetic theory

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

Consider a box filled with a dilute gas. We model the gas as ideal. It is easy to show that the pressure acting on any particular side of the box equals $$p=\frac{mN}{V}v_q^2$$ where $N$- number of molecules, $V$- volume of the box, and $v_q$ - component of speed responsible for reaching the side of the box in question. From this result we could conclude that the pressure acting on any particular side of the box is the same (because no direction is preferred).

My question is two-fold. If the pressure acting on one side is $p$, is the total pressure acting on the box $6p$ because there are $6$ sides? If yes, what happens when we choose another shape as our container, say a sphere? We might say, well pressure acts the same in all directions but this is only true for stationary fluids; if we were to insist on this condition it would be absurd to analyse this in the context of kinetic theory because then $v=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Pressure is a local, isotropic, property of the fluid. It has nothing to do with the shape, or even the presence of a container. If there is an interface, then pressure will lead to a normal force on the interface. More complicated properties of the fluid, such as viscosity, can lead to non-normal forces.

Here: No, the pressure is not multiplied by 6.  Indeed, the shape is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of gravity (or some other acceleration), or if gravity can be neglected because it is relatively small, the pressure is the same on all sides of the box.

No, you cannot add pressures on different sides of the box. This is because pressure is an intensive property, like density and temperature. It does not depend on the number of faces or their area. If it did then the pressure would be infinite inside a sphere.

The forces on each face of the box can be added as vectors, and the resultant force on the box will be zero for any closed shape.

You can add partial pressures from different ideal gases inside the box.

Comment: I understand the answer regarding the addition of pressure, and it was quite foolish to ask given that pressure is intensive. However, I'm still confused by how can the gas molecules remain in motion when the pressure is isotropic? Shouldn't that be the case for stationary fluids?

Comment: @ahra Molecules aren't fluids -- an ensemble of molecules is a fluid. So, a "stationary fluid" is one in which the *mean* velocity of the molecules is zero. In other words, the molecules are zipping around the box in all directions at a wide range of speeds, but the average of all of that motion is zero.

Comment: @ahra  to add COM is at rest

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question of how does the gas stay in motion when the pressure is isotropic.

The pressure is isotropic because we can model the gas as particles that have different speeds from each-other, however for one particular particle we can say that the magnitude for all of it's velocity components is equal because there is no preferred direction and therefore the distribution of velocities is the same for all directions (for every $v_x$ there is a equal $v_y$ and $v_z$). Therefore if we model the gas like this the average velocity components are themselves equal - hence causing the pressure to be isotropic.

Also one of the axioms of the kinetic theory is the conservation of momentum, since the collisions are elastic, so no loss of energy/velocity occurs.